# find position of a view in grid view by having x and y co ordinates

Tags: android, gridview

I am making an android app in which I have x and y coordinates and i need to find position of the view in grid view. I just want to know is there any function or simple method to find the position.

```
 skip this line
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
yourGridView.pointToPosition(yourX, yourY);
```

pointToPosition(int x, int y) is a functions in the GridView class

Answer (score 0):

When a user click on your gridView you can just use this code:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) { 

int clickedPosition = position; 

}}
```

clickedPosition is a variable that contains the position of the clicked view starting from the upper-left side of your gridView and starting by 0

Comment: yes i want to find same position but i doesn't want the click from user.......i have x and y coordinates thats all I have ....

Comment: Sorry but you have the xy cordinates of the page or of the gridView ?

Comment: i don't understand what do you want to do... if you have the xy coordinates of the activity and the gridView are scrollable how you can find the hide elements or if the user scroll the gridview you don't have more the same position... please edit your post with a little bit of code and more explanation